# insert data to a migration without a model

Tags: laravel

How to insert data to a migration (table) without a model in Laravel, a migration with its model in which I define the corresponding relationships and the other only the migration

It can clearly be done according to the documentation of Laravel when you have the migration with your respective model, as follows.

```
$comment = new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);

$post = App\Post::find(1);

$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

or

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$comment = $post->comments()->create([
    'message' => 'A new comment.',
]);
```

This works for me only when I have with their respective models but not as I want to do
I am pending if someone can clarify with this

Answer (score 4):

You can interact with database directly without a model using the `DB` facade:

```
DB::table('tablename')->insert(['column'=>'value']);
```

Same way you can use wheres, selects. For more details see [Laravel docs - Database: Query Builder - Inserts](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#inserts)